# Is it possible to run both tests based on specs2 and scalatest in the same project with SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest, specs2

For a project, I am migrating some tests to ScalaTest in place of Specs2. Is it possible to run, in the same project, tests based on both framework by SBT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's possible. 
Have a look at this activator template mixing several test framework https://github.com/typesafehub/activator-scala-testing it should give you all the details you need.